# Repository is rebasing, action to take to not damage the repository?

Tags: git, smartgit

I'm working in a GIT repo from office and from home. The latest day I work on office I forgot to commit changes to the repo and made changes in the same file but in home where I did the commit. Now when I pull changes from repository, of course, I got problems but I resolve then. Now my repository say `<rebasing>` and I don't know what to since pull is disabled. This is the latest actions I did and I leave a screenshoot of the problem, any help?

```
Resolve
    $ git.exe checkout --ours -- src\Website\BackendBundle\Resources\views\Product\MetaDetailGroup\list.html.twig
    $ git.exe add --force -- src\Website\BackendBundle\Resources\views\Product\MetaDetailGroup\list.html.twig
Pull (Rebase): merge-recursive failed (return code 1)
    $ git.exe fetch --progress --prune origin
    remote: Counting objects: 650, done.
    remote: Total 504 (delta 253), reused 320 (delta 150)
    From 1000.servers.wuelto.com:development/kraken
       758cc34..ade8ca7  develop    -> origin/develop
    First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
    $ git.exe checkout --quiet ade8ca75ff6041fbf242576f7f7266f6ef2fa650
    $ git.exe update-ref ORIG_HEAD 608f32ec641512846e76bb5724e3154bd38687d8
    $ git.exe merge-recursive 608f32ec641512846e76bb5724e3154bd38687d8^ -- ade8ca75ff6041fbf242576f7f7266f6ef2fa650 608f32ec641512846e76bb5724e3154bd38687d8
    Auto-merging src/Website/BackendBundle/Resources/views/Product/MetaDetailGroup/list.html.twig
    CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/Website/BackendBundle/Resources/views/Product/MetaDetailGroup/list.html.twig
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with SmartGit, resolve the conflict in your file (in your case `list.html.twig`):

- when using **Query|Conflict Solver**, SmartGit will ask you whether to stage changes.
- when resolving the conflict manually (outside of SmartGit), invoke **Local|Resolve** once you have fixed the file content.

Then, to finish the *rebase*, use **Commit** or **Branch|Rebase|Continue**.

Note: if anything goes wrong, **Discard** the *rebase* and start over by invoking **Pull** again.